# Getting HTML output from Xcode's built-in static analysis

Tags: xcode, clang-static-analyzer

When I use the Build & Analyze option in Xcode I see a very useful visual output integrated into the IDE, showing code paths, memory leaks, dead-stores, etc.

In Xcode there is a build setting that will allow you to run the static analyser (clang) as part of each build. But when I do this the output is in plain plist files within the build folder.

Is there any way to generate a human viewable HTML output from those plist files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it is something new on Xcode 6 but if you execute from the command line `xcodebuild CLANG_ANALYZER_OTHER_FLAGS= CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT=plist-html CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT_DIR=$HOME/tmp  RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=YES` it generates a directory with html inside of it.

Comment: Thanks for helpful information. Is there a possibility to generate one html  report instead of each warning as a separate html file.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to generate one HTML report instead of different files for each warning

Comment: @vishnu add these commands on the root folder of your project.